# How can I batch decrypt a series of PDF files?

Tags: password, pdf, batch, decryption

I have a bunch of PDF documents I know the password for and would like to decrypt them. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Nautilus script

Automating this task can be easily achieved through a script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# AUTHOR:       (c) Glutanimate 2012 (http://askubuntu.com/users/81372/)
# NAME:         PDFdecrypt 0.3
# DESCRIPTION:  A script to batch decrypt PDF files.
# DEPENDENCIES: qpdf zenity libnotify-bin 
#               (install via sudo apt-get install qpdf zenity libnotify-bin)
# LICENSE:      GNU GPL v3 (http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html)
# CHANGELOG:    0.3 - added notifications and basic error checking
#               0.2 - replaced obsolete gdialog with zenity

password=$(zenity --password --title "PDF Password required")

RET=$?

if [[ $RET = 0 ]]; then

  while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
      ENCRYP=$1
      DECRYP=$(echo "$ENCRYP" | sed 's/\.\w*$/_decrypted.pdf/')
      qpdf --password=$password --decrypt "$ENCRYP" "$DECRYP"
      RET=$?
      if [[ $RET != 0 ]]; then
        ERR=1
      fi
      shift
  done

  if [[ $ERR = 1 ]]
    then
        notify-send -i application-pdf "PDFdecrypt" "All documents processed.There were some errors"
    else
        notify-send -i application-pdf "PDFdecrypt" "All documents decrypted."
  fi

else
  exit
fi
```

**Note**: This script depends on `qpdf`, `zenity` and `libnotify-bin`. Install them with the command provided in the script.

---

**Usage**

Copy and paste the contents of the text box above into a new empty document (right click in file manager: *Create new document* --> *Empty document*) and save it as `Decrypt PDFs`.

Make it executable by marking it as such (right click on file --> *Properties* --> *Permissions*  --> check *Allow executing file as program*).

If you are running Ubuntu you can easily install this script to the context menu of your file manager by copying it to `~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts`. You will now be able to decrypt PDFs by selecting them, right clicking and heading to *Scripts* --> *Decrypt PDFs*. Enjoy!

Comment: Which are packages for installing `gpdf`?

Comment: The package is just called `qpdf` (note: q, not g). It's in the official repositories, so you can just install it via `sudo apt-get install qpdf`.